# Laravel 5 built in User Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel 5 built in User Authentication.In this regard I would like to redirect **user** to a certain route/page/controller after successfully logged in. I am trying to change code of complied.php file. I am trying to change `/home` of below code, but it is not working.

```
trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
    {
        protected $auth;
        protected $registrar;
        public function getRegister()
        {
            return view('auth.register');
        }
        public function postRegister(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
            }
            $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
        public function getLogin()
        {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
        public function postLogin(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, array('email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required'));
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
            if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            }
            return redirect($this->loginPath())->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(array('email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()));
        }
        protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
        {
            return 'These credentials do not match our records.';
        }
        public function getLogout()
        {
            $this->auth->logout();
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        public function redirectPath()
        {
            if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) 
            {
                return $this->redirectPath;
            }
            return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
        }
        public function loginPath()
        {
            return property_exists($this, 'loginPath') ? $this->loginPath : '/auth/login';
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to change anything in `compiled.php`

In `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware change,

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
```

to

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
```

This basically redirects logged in user to desired path, once logged in user returns to website. 
so,`handle` function lookes like below,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

after that add following in `AuthController`

```
public $redirectTo = '/';
public $redirectAfterLogout = '/';
```

so after successful login user wil be redirected to `redirectTo` and after logout user will be redirected to `redirectAfterLogout`.

Comment: Thanks @pinkal vansia. What will happen if expected route don't found ?? Thanks

Comment: What route you are talking about? Gererally you will get Route not found exception.

Comment: Thanks @pinkal vansia. I am getting this error `ErrorException in compiled.php line 7319:
Undefined offset: 1`.

Comment: I got this `  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompil
  ePath()`